# Is there a way of declaring a custom relationship usable from Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, uiviewcontroller

iOS 5 supports custom composite view controllers much like the built in ones (tab bar, navigation controller). However, I cannot figure out how you're supposed to set up the relationships between your custom parent view controller and sub view controller(s). I would like to be able to declare a relationship and have it hooked up in Interface Builder as made possible with the built in ones.

Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Comment: what you want ? tabbar and navigation bar on single page ?

Comment: @krunal - no, I want my own composite view controller that overlays some information on top of another view.

Comment: make one controller as RootViewController and add another controller as subview to it..

Comment: @krunal, I want to set up the relationship between my (reusable) view controller and another view the same way it's done with tab bar and navigation controller, i e defining a relationship between the two, but I cannot find a way of defining a custom relationship that Interface Builder understands.

Comment: So... you want to create your own composite view controller (e.g. something like SideBarViewController?). Can't say I've seen this done anywhere, not with custom implementation. Which is what krunal suggested.